# python kohonen.py algorithm dimension and shape definition

Tags: python, neural-network, som

I am trying to use [this python library](https://github.com/lmjohns3/kohonen) to do a kohonen map.

However I don't know what these parameters really are?
For example:
https://github.com/lmjohns3/kohonen/blob/master/kohonen/kohonen.py#L150

what are dimension and shape? Can somebody help me to run a example on this?

```
dimension=None,
shape=None,
```

> dimension: The length of a neuron vector in a Map or a Gas. 
> shape: The
>   shape of the neuron topology in whatever Map or Gas we are building.

I need an example to illustrate this, otherwise it is not very clear.